# Most efficient way to calculate pairwise similarity of 250k lists

Tags: python, matrix

I have 250,000 lists containing an average of 100 strings each, stored across 10 dictionaries.  I need to calculate the pairwise similarity of all lists (the similarity metric isn't relevant here; but, briefly, it involves taking the intersection of the two lists and normalizing the result by some constant).

The code I've come up with for the pairwise comparisons is quite straightforward. I'm just using itertools.product to compare every list to every other list.  The problem is performing these calculations on  250,000 lists in a time-efficient way.   To anyone who's dealt with a similar problem: Which of the usual options (scipy, PyTables) is best for this in terms of the following criteria:

- supports python data types
- smartly stores a very sparse matrix (approx 80% of the values will be 0)
- efficient (can do the calculations in under 10 hours)

Comment: What do you want to do with the matrix afterwards? You could just write it out to a file in long format, like `A B 1\nA C 2\nA D 3\n`, which would avoid having to store it all in memory, and would further take advantage of the sparseness (you can skip lines with 0). Do you need to follow this with matrix operations or something like that?

Comment: No, I only need the resulting matrix of pairwise similarities. I'm not doing any matrix operations on the results.

Comment: If two lists with no common elements will always have similarity zero, then you can save yourself a lot of unnecessary computation by doing a linear pass to build a dictionary where the keys are the words and the values are sets of strings/string indices where those words appear.  Then linearly loop over the string lists, and perform a similarity computation only involving the source string list and the possible target string lists (namely, those in the union of the sets corresponding to each word in the source.)

Comment: the efficient way might be to change your algorithm from `O(nlists**2 * similarity_op_cost)` to e.g., `O(nlists*log(nlists) + nlists*similarity_op_cost)` (using an analog of suffix arrays for substring problem). Depending on what do you want to do with the result KDTree-like structure might help to improve the time complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you just want the most efficient way to determine the distance between any two points in your data?

Or do you actually need this *m x m* distance matrix that stores all pair-wise similarity values for all rows in your data?

Usually it's far more efficient to persist your data in some metric space, 
using a data structure optimized for rapid retrieval, than it is to 
pre-calculate the pair-wise similarity values in advance and just look them up.
Needless to say, the distance matrix option scales horribly--
n data points requires an n x n distance matrix to store the pair-wise
similarity scores.

A *kd-tree* is the technique of choice for data of small dimension
("small" here means something like number of features less than about 20);
*Voronoi tesselation* is often preferred for higher dimension data.

Much more recently, the ***ball tree*** has been used as a superior alternative
to both--it has the performance of the *kd-tree* but without the degradation
at high dimension.

***[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#installing-from-source)*** has an excellent implementation which includes 
unit tests. It is well-documented and currently under active development.

*scikit-learn* is built on *NumPy* and *SciPy* and so both are dependencies. The various [installation options](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#installing-from-source) for *scikit-learn* are provided on the Site.

The most common use case for Ball Trees is in *k-Nearest Neighbors*; but it will
work quite well on its own, eg., in cases like the one described in the OP.

you can use the *scikit-learn Ball Tree* implementation like so:

```
>>> # create some fake data--a 2D NumPy array having 10,000 rows and 10 columns
>>> D = NP.random.randn(10000 * 10).reshape(10000, 10)

>>> # import the BallTree class (here bound to a local variable of same name)
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree as BallTree

>>> # call the constructor, passing in the data array and a 'leaf size'
>>> # the ball tree is instantiated and populated in the single step below:

>>> BT = BallTree(D, leaf_size=5, p=2)

>>> # 'leaf size' specifies the data (number of points) at which 
>>> # point brute force search is triggered
>>> # 'p' specifies the distance metric, p=2 (the default) for Euclidean;
>>> # setting p equal to 1, sets Manhattan (aka 'taxi cab' or 'checkerboard' dist)

>>> type(BT)
    <type 'sklearn.neighbors.ball_tree.BallTree'>
```

instantiating & populating the ball tree is ***very fast***
(timed using Corey Goldberg's [timer class](https://gist.github.com/2942781)):

```
>>> with Timer() as t:
        BT = BallTree(D, leaf_size=5)

>>> "ball tree instantiated & populated in {0:2f} milliseconds".format(t.elapsed)
        'ball tree instantiated & populated in 13.90 milliseconds'
```

querying the ball tree is also ***fast***:

an example query: *provide the three data points closest to the  data point row index 500*; *and for each of them, return their index and their distance from this reference point at D[500,:]*

```
>>> # ball tree has an instance method, 'query' which returns pair-wise distance
>>> # and an index; one distance and index is returned per 'pair' of data points

>>> dx, idx = BT.query(D[500,:], k=3)

>>> dx    # distance
    array([[ 0.   ,  1.206,  1.58 ]])

>>> idx    # index
    array([[500, 556, 373]], dtype=int32)

>>> with Timer() as t:
    dx, idx = BT.query(D[500,:], k=3)


>>> "query results returned in {0:2f} milliseconds".format(t.elapsed)
        'query results returned in 15.85 milliseconds'
```

The default distance metric in the scikit-learn Ball Tree implementation is ***Minkowski***, which is just a generalization of Euclidean and Manhattan (ie, in the Minkowski expression, there is a parameter, p, which when set to 2 collapses to Euclidean, and Manhattan, for p=1.

Answer (score 0):

If you define appropriate distance (similarity) function then some functions from [scipy.spatial.distance](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) might help